# Google App Engine - how to set up an SSL for Custom Domain

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, dns, certificate, ssl-certificate

Google App Engine offers [SSL for Custom Domains](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl), but I'm not sure how to properly set it up with my app. Say I'm running `myapp.appspot.com` and I own `myapp.com`, can someone explain to me the exact steps I need to take in order to make my App Engine app serve on my .com domain?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the basic process of setting up a custom domain is described here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Is there something in that article that isn't clear?

The article does delegate an important part of the process, which is setting up a Google Apps account for your domain (see "Otherwise, click Sign up for Google Apps and continue with this step." in step 3).  A key part of setting that up is verifying you own the domain you're trying to set up.  This requires that you make a small modification to your site, or serve a DNS TXT record.  Read more about it here:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60216